# How to query multiple elements that start with the same ID and then check whether the input has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a list of text inputs which all start with the same id but are slightly different at the end. When text is entered by the user in any of these input fields I want to execute a function. At the moment this is working with the following code:

```
var heightInches = document.querySelector("#Height_Inches");
var heightFeet = document.querySelector("#Height_Feet");
var heightCentimeters = document.querySelector("#Height_Centimeters");

      heightInches.oninput = function (e) {
         console.log("Edited");
      }
      heightFeet.oninput = function (e) {
         console.log("Edited");
      }
      heightCentimeters.oninput = function (e) {
         console.log("Edited")
      }
```

The issue is that I don't like the repetition and would rather query all of the ids that begin with "Height_" and do something (as what is excuted inside each function will be the same.

Here is what I have tried but does not work:

```
var allHeight = document.querySelector('[id*="Height_"]');

allHeight.oninput = function (e) {
  console.log("edited"); 
}
```

I have also tried the same with `querySelectorAll`

Please could someone help with where I am going wrong here? Every other Stack Overflow answer and article I see seems to suggest that `id*` is the correct way to select? Thank you

Comment: The simplest and most performant way would be to put the same class on all the elements and select them by that. In any case you need to use `querySelectorAll()` (as you're targeting *multiple* elements) and then loop through them to attach the event handler, for which you should use `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for.

The only thing you were missing is looping through your elements.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="Height_"]');

inputs.forEach( input => {
    input.oninput = function (e) {
      console.log("edited"); 
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Height_1">
<input type="text" id="Height_2">
<input type="text" id="Height_3">
```

Comment: Thank you @Baldrani . I have put this in my code but it did not log to the console. When I inserted a break point, it looped through the elements on page load, but as nothing has been inserted yet, it did not console.log. Is there any way to make sure that this listens constantly rather than just once ?

Comment: Don't worry, I have solved this now by adding in an event listener into the loop. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an ID, which is intended to be unique, why not add a class like `.height-input` to each input and then you can select them all?

```js
// Get elements
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.height-input');
const outputEl = document.querySelector('.output');

// Attach event handlers
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].oninput = function(e) {
        // Handle input
        outputEl.innerHTML = `Input received on #${e.target.id}`;
    }
}
```

```css
.output {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="height-input" id="HeightInches">
<input type="text" class="height-input" id="HeightFeet">
<input type="text" class="height-input" id="HeightCentimeters">

<div class="output">Waiting for input...</div>
```